# Using Drush on a site installed via Composer

Tags: 8, drush, composer

I had a Drupal 8 project installed from Drupal 8 sources what had been downloaded from Drupal 8 site. Recently I heard a good thought that it would be more comfortable to have the project originally installed via Composer. I did the migration and now the project has a structure likewise installed via Composer. That is, it has the "web" subdirectory with Drupal 8 files, the "vendor" directory isn't included in Drupal files and so on.

The site worked successfully after migration.

However, I ran into a problem. Namely, after migration, I couldn't use Drush on the project. The following error appeared upon trying to execute `drush cr`.

> Command cache-rebuild needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
> Command cache-rebuild requires Drupal core version 8+ to run.

My colleagues advised me to install Drush-launcher from GitHub as a shell for original Drush. I did it, this problem seemingly disappeared. But I ran into a next one. Namely, Now I can't use Drush for projects made on Drupal 7.

Is it possible to set up Drush for sites installed via Composer and without using the launcher?

Comment: Install Drush 8 **globally**, that'll cover your Drupal 7 projects, and install drush 9 **locally** to drupal 8 sites. The launcher will take care of the rest

Comment: I have Drush 8 installed globally.
And I have the "drush/drush" package version 9 in my Drupal 8 project.
Is it not sufficient?
How and where can I install Drush 9 locally ?

Comment: If you have drush 8 why can't you use drush for projects made on drupal 7? drush 8 supports drupal 7. You shouldn't even need the launcher, drush is smart enough to work it out any time i've installed it

Comment: If I use modified Drush (with drush launcher), upon working with Drupal 7 projects I see this error message.

The Drush launcher could not find a Drupal site to operate on. Please do *one* of the following:
  - Navigate to any where within your Drupal project and try again.
  - Add --root=/path/to/drupal so Drush knows where your site is located.

Otherwise, if I use original Drush 8, I can't work with Drupal 8 projects installed via Composer.

I forgot to notify before that I use Windows 7 + Acquia Dev Desktop.

Comment: Oh it's Windows? Windows is notoriously buggy with both PHP and Drush. If you can convert to a linux VM you'll probably find life a lot easier. I'm on a Mac and I've never run into the problems you're describing

Comment: Unfortunately, I use the PC not only programming and it has a lot of other soft for Windows. Do you know, is it possible to set up original Drush 8 for working with Composer projects? As I understand original Drush can't find settings.php file.

Comment: Yeah, just `composer remove drush/drush` from your project. Then you'll be using the system one (assuming you also remove the launcher)

Comment: I did it, but "drush cr" doesn't work.
It writes: Command cache-rebuild needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a     [error]

more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
Command cache-rebuild requires Drupal core version 8+ to run

Comment: You'll need to run it in the Drupal docroot, not the project root. That's usually /docroot or /web

Comment: I tried to did it, there were some errors.
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drush\Commands\DrushCommands' not found in D:\devdesktop\pal\drush\Commands\PolicyCommands.php on line 11
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php:0
PHP   2. drush_main() D:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\tools\vendor\drush\drush\drush.php:12
..

Comment: I think you should remove everything and start again, sounds like you have conflicts in there somehow

Comment: I have posted an answer, but you should update your question: 1) Add that you use Windows 7 + Acquia Dev Desktop. 2) What was the error when running Drush for the Drupal 7 site? With this info, we/I could have provided a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Acquia Dev Desktop comes with Drush included, and I assume that you could just continue to use that for Drupal 7. However, since you installed Drush Launcher and are using it as `drush` (`drush.bat`), you are shadowing it. Break the shadowing by renaming one of the two.

Comment: I use two different bat-files for executing two drush versions for work with these sites.